# what does it mean by upstream projects in JBOSS?

Tags: jboss, terminology, projects

JBOSS developer site lists several projects as upstream projects.  There are more than 90 projects and it does not look like JBOSS created them(Camel,Cxf,tomcat etc....)

what does this term mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According JBoss page:

> **Upstream Projects**
>
> JBoss redefined the application server back in 2002 when it broke
>   apart the monolithic designs of the past with its modular
>   architecture. Since then we’ve continued to find new ways to challenge
>   convention and redefine Enterprise Java through community-driven
>   projects. Community projects represent the latest technologies for use
>   in cutting-edge applications and offer best-effort, community support.

Basically the upstream projects represents the Open Source version of Enterprise products.

Eg.:

**RHQ** - upstream open source project of *JBoss Opetation Network*.
**JBoss Tools** - upstream open source project of *Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio*.

Other Enterprise projects are a combination of Open Source projects, like *Red Hat JBoss BPM Suite* (Drools Expert,  Drools Guvnor, Drools Fusion,  jBPM, OptaPlanner). And some enterprise products can include Open Source products not  "created by JBoss" like *Red Hat JBoss A-MQ* where core messaging is provided by *Apache ActiveMQ*.